# How to access a JSONArray() variable inside of Spring Boot 4?

Tags: java, json, spring

This seems like a fairly straightforward question, and I'm sure that the answer is just as simple, but I am completely lost as to how to access elements within a JSONArray that I've created and passed into my code.

JSONArray rowList = new JSONArray();

```
    for(int i = 0; i < slackIdList.size();i++) {
        JSONObject rowObject = new JSONObject();

        rowObject.put("name", nameList.get(i));         

        rowList.put(rowObject);
    }
```

I've then passed this rowList with the following code:

```
        model.addAttribute("rowList", gson.toJson(rowList));
```

And and calling it in this manner:

```
    var rows = ${rowList};
```

Attempting to access this JSONArray that I've passed with:

```
    cell2.innerHTML = rows.rowObject.name;
```

doesn't seem to work. I'm trying to fill out a table with the name element from each separate JSONObject inside of the array, but cannot find a way to do so correctly. Is there something that I'm missing here that I should be doing?

Edit: posted code:

```
function ShowHours() {

    var rows = ${rowList};
    var name = ${nameList};
    var weekTotal = ${lastWeek};
    var monthTotal = ${lastMonth};
    var yearTotal = ${lastYear};
    var weekAverage = ${averageWeekList};
    var slackIds = ${slackIds};
    var incompleteClocks = ${incompleteClock};
    console.log(rows);
    //var searchTotal = ${FSearchTotal}; will be implemented later, with a function to enter the number of days to look back on.

    var table = document.getElementById("totalHours-table");
    for (i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
    var row = table.insertRow(i+1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);


    cell1.innerHTML = '<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/clocksummaries/' + slackIds[i] + '">' + name[i] + ' (' + incompleteClocks[i] + ')</a>';
    cell2.innerHTML = rows[i];
    cell3.innerHTML = monthTotal[i];
    cell4.innerHTML = yearTotal[i];
    cell5.innerHTML = weekAverage[i];


    }
```

I'm specifically concerned with trying to get cell2 to display something from rows, which is made of a JSONArray of rowObjects put into rowList.

[Output/generated code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9R5wl.png)

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Home</title>
<!-- JQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
              href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
              crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
              href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
              integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp"
              crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script
                src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
                crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<style>
@CHARSET "UTF-8";
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    overflow: scroll;
}
#background {
    background-image: url(../images/npiTableBackground.jpg);
    height: 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: #5C7F9A;
}
#totalHours-table {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px #333333;
    border-collapse: separate;
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color: #81b9e6;
    overflow: scroll;
}
#totalHours-table th, #totalHours-table td {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px #333;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.darktext {
    color: #323232;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
#totalHours-table tr:nth-child(even) {
    border-bottom: 3px #fff;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    cruiser: pointer;

}
#totalHours-table tr:nth-child(odd) {
    border-bottom: 3px #fff;
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    cruiser: pointer;
}

#totalHours-table tr:hover {
    border-bottom: 3px #fff;
    background-color: #d1d1d1;
}

th {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #5F5F5F;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cruiser: pointer;
}
#title {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    width: 550px;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
h1 {
    padding-top: 40px;
    font-size: 36px;
    text-align: center;
 font-family:   
 padding-bottom: 0px;
}
.search {
    height: 40px;
    width: 170%;
}
#searchInput {
    height: 30px;
    width: 24%;

}
#clocksummary-table {
    background-color: #bdcedb;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">


    function ShowHours() {

        var rows = {"myArrayList":[{"map":{"lastYear":"Hours this year: 930","incompleteClocks":1,"name":"Bernard Guiang","lastMonth":"Hours this month: 0","slackIds":"U5DJEKHD5","lastWeek":"Hours this week: 0","averageWeek":"Average Weekly Hours: 17"}},{"map":{"lastYear":"Hours this year: 938","incompleteClocks":3,"name":"Charles Lima","lastMonth":"Hours this month: 0","slackIds":"U5BSAA4UR","lastWeek":"Hours this week: 0","averageWeek":"Average Weekly Hours: 18"}},{"map":{"lastYear":"Hours this year: 29","incompleteClocks":0,"name":"Niki Penrose","lastMonth":"Hours this month: 0","slackIds":"UC7RH34E6","lastWeek":"Hours this week: 0","averageWeek":"Average Weekly Hours: 0"}},{"map":{"lastYear":"Hours this year: 321","incompleteClocks":1,"name":"Pooja Kedia","lastMonth":"Hours this month: 0","slackIds":"UD6KJ6E6B","lastWeek":"Hours this week: 0","averageWeek":"Average Weekly Hours: 6"}},{"map":{"lastYear":"Hours this year: 38","incompleteClocks":6,"name":"Mukund Khanwalker","lastMonth":"Hours this month: 0","slackIds":"UC43FAYNQ","lastWeek":"Hours this week: 0","averageWeek":"Average Weekly Hours: 0"}},{"map":{"lastYear":"Hours this year: 125","incompleteClocks":2,"name":"Bernard Silverman","lastMonth":"Hours this month: 0","slackIds":"U9LQESSMQ","lastWeek":"Hours this week: 0","averageWeek":"Average Weekly Hours: 2"}},{"map":{"lastYear":"Hours this year: 848","incompleteClocks":38,"name":"Neel Mehta","lastMonth":"Hours this month: 0","slackIds":"U03UGNMBS","lastWeek":"Hours this week: 0","averageWeek":"Average Weekly Hours: 16"}},{"map":{"lastYear":"Hours this year: 92","incompleteClocks":0,"name":"Shanika Habib","lastMonth":"Hours this month: 0","slackIds":"U7FRPC4D7","lastWeek":"Hours this week: 0","averageWeek":"Average Weekly Hours: 1"}},{"map":{"lastYear":"Hours this year: 178","incompleteClocks":0,"name":"Nicholas Steele","lastMonth":"Hours this month: 0","slackIds":"UAY59VBBP","lastWeek":"Hours this week: 0","averageWeek":"Average Weekly Hours: 3"}},{"map":{"lastYear":"Hours this year: 113","incompleteClocks":1,"name":"Sankshay","lastMonth":"Hours this month: 0","slackIds":"UCGATG672","lastWeek":"Hours this week: 0","averageWeek":"Average Weekly Hours: 2"}},{"map":{"lastYear":"Hours this year: 180","incompleteClocks":0,"name":"Daniel Han","lastMonth":"Hours this month: 0","slackIds":"U8JFK0NNA","lastWeek":"Hours this week: 0","averageWeek":"Average Weekly Hours: 3"}},{"map":{"lastYear":"Hours this year: 239","incompleteClocks":0,"name":"Jessica Acosta","lastMonth":"Hours this month: 0","slackIds":"UAS1PBEJ2","lastWeek":"Hours this week: 0","averageWeek":"Average Weekly Hours: 4"}},{"map":{"lastYear":"Hours this year: 116","incompleteClocks":0,"name":"Faiyaj Murshed","lastMonth":"Hours this month: 0","slackIds":"UDSA9QKEZ","lastWeek":"Hours this week: 0","averageWeek":"Average Weekly Hours: 2"}},{"map":{"lastYear":"Hours this year: 714","incompleteClocks":1,"name":"Jing He","lastMonth":"Hours this month: 0","slackIds":"UBHNQH98B","lastWeek":"Hours this week: 0","averageWeek":"Average Weekly Hours: 13"}},{"map":{"lastYear":"Hours this year: 212","incompleteClocks":0,"name":"Suzie","lastMonth":"Hours this month: 0","slackIds":"UD0N8HHSN","lastWeek":"Hours this week: 0","averageWeek":"Average Weekly Hours: 4"}},{"map":{"lastYear":"Hours this year: 226","incompleteClocks":2,"name":"Heba Tarin","lastMonth":"Hours this month: 0","slackIds":"UAQFWJ370","lastWeek":"Hours this week: 0","averageWeek":"Average Weekly Hours: 4"}},{"map":{"lastYear":"Hours this year: 211","incompleteClocks":2,"name":"Smita Gopalakrishnan","lastMonth":"Hours this month: 0","slackIds":"UBH4E0CEM","lastWeek":"Hours this week: 0","averageWeek":"Average Weekly Hours: 4"}},{"map":{"lastYear":"Hours this year: 4","incompleteClocks":0,"name":"Nikhil Paul","lastMonth":"Hours this month: 0","slackIds":"UANUN3N56","lastWeek":"Hours this week: 0","averageWeek":"Average Weekly Hours: 0"}},{"map":{"lastYear":"Hours this year: 14","incompleteClocks":6,"name":"Hari Krishnan","lastMonth":"Hours this month: 0","slackIds":"UDF0E46G0","lastWeek":"Hours this week: 0","averageWeek":"Average Weekly Hours: 0"}},{"map":{"lastYear":"Hours this year: 1153","incompleteClocks":6,"name":"Robert Yao","lastMonth":"Hours this month: 0","slackIds":"U042YHEGY","lastWeek":"Hours this week: 0","averageWeek":"Average Weekly Hours: 22"}},{"map":{"lastYear":"Hours this year: 84","incompleteClocks":4,"name":"Eleni Kapogianis","lastMonth":"Hours this month: 0","slackIds":"U8XB46ENL","lastWeek":"Hours this week: 0","averageWeek":"Average Weekly Hours: 1"}},{"map":{"lastYear":"Hours this year: 24","incompleteClocks":1,"name":"Shivam Dass","lastMonth":"Hours this month: 0","slackIds":"UB192QU4S","lastWeek":"Hours this week: 0","averageWeek":"Average Weekly Hours: 0"}},{"map":{"lastYear":"Hours this year: 40","incompleteClocks":1,"name":"Allan George","lastMonth":"Hours this month: 0","slackIds":"UE8MAMVDW","lastWeek":"Hours this week: 0","averageWeek":"Average Weekly Hours: 0"}},{"map":{"lastYear":"Hours this year: 121","incompleteClocks":0,"name":"Magaly Rincon","lastMonth":"Hours this month: 0","slackIds":"UERDDKM8U","lastWeek":"Hours this week: 0","averageWeek":"Average Weekly Hours: 2"}},{"map":{"lastYear":"Hours this year: 6","incompleteClocks":1,"name":"Trang Ngo","lastMonth":"Hours this month: 0","slackIds":"UF7PKMB8Q","lastWeek":"Hours this week: 0","averageWeek":"Average Weekly Hours: 0"}},{"map":{"lastYear":"Hours this year: 90","incompleteClocks":0,"name":"Michael Keller","lastMonth":"Hours this month: 0","slackIds":"UFFFRFP63","lastWeek":"Hours this week: 0","averageWeek":"Average Weekly Hours: 1"}},{"map":{"lastYear":"Hours this year: 38","incompleteClocks":0,"name":"Bineetha Aluri","lastMonth":"Hours this month: 0","slackIds":"UFREPU4PL","lastWeek":"Hours this week: 0","averageWeek":"Average Weekly Hours: 0"}},{"map":{"lastYear":"Hours this year: 180","incompleteClocks":0,"name":"Nour Alhamwi","lastMonth":"Hours this month: 0","slackIds":"UFVP0BN7N","lastWeek":"Hours this week: 0","averageWeek":"Average Weekly Hours: 3"}},{"map":{"lastYear":"Hours this year: 99","incompleteClocks":0,"name":"Phillip Bondank","lastMonth":"Hours this month: 0","slackIds":"UG6L57Z5L","lastWeek":"Hours this week: 0","averageWeek":"Average Weekly Hours: 1"}},{"map":{"lastYear":"Hours this year: 0","incompleteClocks":1,"name":"Sydney Fikse","lastMonth":"Hours this month: 0","slackIds":"UG79CQ0HY","lastWeek":"Hours this week: 0","averageWeek":"Average Weekly Hours: 0"}},{"map":{"lastYear":"Hours this year: 55","incompleteClocks":0,"name":"Katie Nguyen","lastMonth":"Hours this month: 0","slackIds":"UGNF7L8NA","lastWeek":"Hours this week: 0","averageWeek":"Average Weekly Hours: 1"}},{"map":{"lastYear":"Hours this year: 2","incompleteClocks":0,"name":"Megan Hall","lastMonth":"Hours this month: 0","slackIds":"UGTRN6T4M","lastWeek":"Hours this week: 0","averageWeek":"Average Weekly Hours: 0"}},{"map":{"lastYear":"Hours this year: 56","incompleteClocks":1,"name":"Armaan Dodd","lastMonth":"Hours this month: 0","slackIds":"UGUQJMR4L","lastWeek":"Hours this week: 0","averageWeek":"Average Weekly Hours: 1"}},{"map":{"lastYear":"Hours this year: 0","incompleteClocks":0,"name":"Anish Raju","lastMonth":"Hours this month: 0","slackIds":"UGY78DEBC","lastWeek":"Hours this week: 0","averageWeek":"Average Weekly Hours: 0"}}]};
        var name = ["Bernard Guiang","Charles Lima","Niki Penrose","Pooja Kedia","Mukund Khanwalker","Bernard Silverman","Neel Mehta","Shanika Habib","Nicholas Steele","Sankshay","Daniel Han","Jessica Acosta","Faiyaj Murshed","Jing He","Suzie","Heba Tarin","Smita Gopalakrishnan","Nikhil Paul","Hari Krishnan","Robert Yao","Eleni Kapogianis","Shivam Dass","Allan George","Magaly Rincon","Trang Ngo","Michael Keller","Bineetha Aluri","Nour Alhamwi","Phillip Bondank","Sydney Fikse","Katie Nguyen","Megan Hall","Armaan Dodd","Anish Raju"];
        var weekTotal = ["Hours this week: 0","Hours this week: 0","Hours this week: 0","Hours this week: 0","Hours this week: 0","Hours this week: 0","Hours this week: 0","Hours this week: 0","Hours this week: 0","Hours this week: 0","Hours this week: 0","Hours this week: 0","Hours this week: 0","Hours this week: 0","Hours this week: 0","Hours this week: 0","Hours this week: 0","Hours this week: 0","Hours this week: 0","Hours this week: 0","Hours this week: 0","Hours this week: 0","Hours this week: 0","Hours this week: 0","Hours this week: 0","Hours this week: 0","Hours this week: 0","Hours this week: 0","Hours this week: 0","Hours this week: 0","Hours this week: 0","Hours this week: 0","Hours this week: 0","Hours this week: 0"];
        var monthTotal = ["Hours this month: 0","Hours this month: 0","Hours this month: 0","Hours this month: 0","Hours this month: 0","Hours this month: 0","Hours this month: 0","Hours this month: 0","Hours this month: 0","Hours this month: 0","Hours this month: 0","Hours this month: 0","Hours this month: 0","Hours this month: 0","Hours this month: 0","Hours this month: 0","Hours this month: 0","Hours this month: 0","Hours this month: 0","Hours this month: 0","Hours this month: 0","Hours this month: 0","Hours this month: 0","Hours this month: 0","Hours this month: 0","Hours this month: 0","Hours this month: 0","Hours this month: 0","Hours this month: 0","Hours this month: 0","Hours this month: 0","Hours this month: 0","Hours this month: 0","Hours this month: 0"];
        var yearTotal = ["Hours this year: 930","Hours this year: 938","Hours this year: 29","Hours this year: 321","Hours this year: 38","Hours this year: 125","Hours this year: 848","Hours this year: 92","Hours this year: 178","Hours this year: 113","Hours this year: 180","Hours this year: 239","Hours this year: 116","Hours this year: 714","Hours this year: 212","Hours this year: 226","Hours this year: 211","Hours this year: 4","Hours this year: 14","Hours this year: 1153","Hours this year: 84","Hours this year: 24","Hours this year: 40","Hours this year: 121","Hours this year: 6","Hours this year: 90","Hours this year: 38","Hours this year: 180","Hours this year: 99","Hours this year: 0","Hours this year: 55","Hours this year: 2","Hours this year: 56","Hours this year: 0"];
        var weekAverage = ["Average Weekly Hours: 17","Average Weekly Hours: 18","Average Weekly Hours: 0","Average Weekly Hours: 6","Average Weekly Hours: 0","Average Weekly Hours: 2","Average Weekly Hours: 16","Average Weekly Hours: 1","Average Weekly Hours: 3","Average Weekly Hours: 2","Average Weekly Hours: 3","Average Weekly Hours: 4","Average Weekly Hours: 2","Average Weekly Hours: 13","Average Weekly Hours: 4","Average Weekly Hours: 4","Average Weekly Hours: 4","Average Weekly Hours: 0","Average Weekly Hours: 0","Average Weekly Hours: 22","Average Weekly Hours: 1","Average Weekly Hours: 0","Average Weekly Hours: 0","Average Weekly Hours: 2","Average Weekly Hours: 0","Average Weekly Hours: 1","Average Weekly Hours: 0","Average Weekly Hours: 3","Average Weekly Hours: 1","Average Weekly Hours: 0","Average Weekly Hours: 1","Average Weekly Hours: 0","Average Weekly Hours: 1","Average Weekly Hours: 0"];
        var slackIds = ["U5DJEKHD5","U5BSAA4UR","UC7RH34E6","UD6KJ6E6B","UC43FAYNQ","U9LQESSMQ","U03UGNMBS","U7FRPC4D7","UAY59VBBP","UCGATG672","U8JFK0NNA","UAS1PBEJ2","UDSA9QKEZ","UBHNQH98B","UD0N8HHSN","UAQFWJ370","UBH4E0CEM","UANUN3N56","UDF0E46G0","U042YHEGY","U8XB46ENL","UB192QU4S","UE8MAMVDW","UERDDKM8U","UF7PKMB8Q","UFFFRFP63","UFREPU4PL","UFVP0BN7N","UG6L57Z5L","UG79CQ0HY","UGNF7L8NA","UGTRN6T4M","UGUQJMR4L","UGY78DEBC"];
        var incompleteClocks = [1,3,0,1,6,2,38,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,2,2,0,6,6,4,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0];
        console.log(rows);
        //var searchTotal = ; will be implemented later, with a function to enter the number of days to look back on.

        var table = document.getElementById("totalHours-table");
        for (i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
        var row = table.insertRow(i+1);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);


        cell1.innerHTML = '<a href="/admin/clocksummaries/' + slackIds[i] + '">' + name[i] + ' (' + incompleteClocks[i] + ')</a>';
        cell2.innerHTML = rows[i];
        cell3.innerHTML = monthTotal[i];
        cell4.innerHTML = yearTotal[i];
        cell5.innerHTML = weekAverage[i];


        }

    }

    function filterNPI() {
        var rawFilter = document.getElementById("searchInput");
        var filter = rawFilter.value.toUpperCase();
        var table = document.getElementById("clocksummary-table");
        var tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        var td;
        155
        for (i=0; i<tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
            if (td) {
                if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
    } 

    function predicateBy(prop){
           return function(a,b){
              if( a[prop] > b[prop]){
                  return 1;
              }else if( a[prop] < b[prop] ){
                  return -1;
              }
              return 0;
           }
        }

    function sortTableByColumn(columnNumber) {
          var tableElement=document.getElementById("totalHours-table");
          [].slice.call(tableElement.tBodies[0].rows).sort(function(a, b) {
            return (
              a.cells[columnNumber-1].textContent<b.cells[columnNumber-1].textContent?-1:
              a.cells[columnNumber-1].textContent>b.cells[columnNumber-1].textContent?1:
              0);
          }).forEach(function(val, index) {
            tableElement.tBodies[0].appendChild(val);
          });
        }

    function goToLink() {
          slackId = document.getElementById("totalHours-table").cell5;
          window.location = "/admin/clocksummaries/"+slackId; 
        }





    $(document).ready( function() {
        ShowHours();
    });


    </script>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="/resources/css/style.css" />
<body id="background">
<div>
<nav class="navbar-default navbar-fixed-top " role="navigation" >
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: #5C7F9A;">
<div class="navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: #839FB5;">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar"> </button>
                            <a class="navbar-" rel="home" href="/home" title="EpiFinder">
                            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/6IiGnIv.png" width="16px" height="16px" id="navbar-logo" style="max-width: 100px;">
                            <span class="active" > <a id="home_link" href="/home" class="darktext"> Home</a> |
                            <a id="signout_link" href="/logout" class="darktext"> Sign Out</a> |
                            <a id="home_link" href="/admin/totalHours" class="darktext"> Total Hours</a> 
</div>
<div class="container mt-5 pt-5">
  <h1>Clocksummary Home</h1>
  <!-- <div id="title">
        <h2>
            Search for your preferred doctor. <br> <br>
        </h2>
        </div> -->

  <div class = "search" >
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search for clocksummary dates" id="searchInput" onKeyUp="sortTable();">
  </div>
    <table id="totalHours-table" width="100%">
    <tr bgcolor="#959595">
      <th title="Username" onclick="sortTable(0)">Name (Incomplete Clocks)</th>
      <th title="Weekly total hours">Week Total Hours</th>
      <th title="Monthly total hours">Month Total Hours</th>
      <th title="Yearly total hours">Year Total Hours</th>
      <th title="Weekly average hours">Average Weekly Hours</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<script>
function sortTable(n) {
      var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
      table = document.getElementById("totalHours-Table");
      switching = true;
      dir = "asc"; 
      while (switching) {
        switching = false;
        rows = table.rows;
        //rows = table.getelementby
        for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
          shouldSwitch = false;
          x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
          y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];

          if (dir == "asc") {
            if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {

              shouldSwitch = true;
              break;
            }
          } else if (dir == "desc") {
            if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
              shouldSwitch = true;
              break;
            }
          }
        }
        if (shouldSwitch) {
          rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
          switching = true;
          switchcount ++; 
        } else {
          if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
            dir = "desc";
            switching = true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
/*
function sortTable() {
    var table = document.getElementById("clocksummary-table");
    var switching = true;
    var x, y, shouldSwitch;

    while(switching) {
        switching = false;
        var rows = table.rows;
        for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
            shouldSwitch = false;
            x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
            y = rows[i+1].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];

              if (Number(x.innerHTML) > Number(y.innerHTML)) {
                shouldSwitch = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (shouldSwitch) {
            rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i+1], rows[i]);
            switching = true;
        }
        }

}
*/
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: First, forget about the Java part, since the problem is with JavaScript, executing in the browser. So, look at the HTML code generated by your server (right-click -> view source), and post that. If I analyze the code correctly, `rows` is a JavaScript array. Arrays don't have any `rowObject` attribute. They're an ordered sequence of elements, just like Java arrays. You access the third element using `rows[2]`

Comment: Apologies, I've set it up as a JSONArray Object, or an array  of JSON Objects. I should not have included the java tag in my question, and I will edit that to reflect that.

However, the rowObject is just one of the objects that has been placed into the object itself, in the loop inside of my controller class listed above.

I seem to still be having trouble accessing the elements themselves; using rows[2] or rows.rowObject both return my table by filling those elements with just the text "undefined", leading me to believe that my issue may be in the creation in my controller class?

Comment: But you still haven't posted the generated HTML/JS code, making it much harder than necessary to diagnose the problem. Post it.

Comment: Posted. Adding a picture of the console.log of the array itself, as well.

Comment: You still haven't posted the generated HTML/JS code. I.e. what does `var rows = ${rowList};`become once the server has evaluated that code? Right-click in your browser, click "View page source", and post what you see **as text**.

Comment: Apologies, added in

Comment: Now it's clear that `rows` is not an array, but an object with a single property named `myArrayList`, which is an array. This array contains N objects which have a single property named `map`, which is an object with N properties (lastYear, name, etc.). `rows.rowObject.name` thus isn't valid. `rows.myArrayList[0].map.name` would be valid. All you need now is to actually **read** the generated JavaScript code.